# IIS 6 SSL Restore from PFX without Deleting Pending Request

Tags: ssl, iis-6

I requested a new **SSL certificate** from a certificate authority, but until they process it my site is losing business.  Before doing so, I had backed up the original certificate to a PFX file.

Now when I try to restore the backup, it forces me to delete it, or process the request.  Since the new one isn't ready yet, is there any way to restore the backup, without deleting the request?  Or will it cause any issues if I delete the request to install the new one when it comes in?

Server is IIS 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can import the pfx file, but you'll need to delete the pending request first. That means that the cert you get from the cert authority will be no good and you'll have to request a new one, again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking aloud but I imagine you can create a new IIS website and restore the PFX file to it, then modify your host header bindings to run your site on the new IIS website.  Use the "Save Configuration to a File" and "New -> Web Site (from file)" options to clone your existing site so you don't miss any settings in the new one.

While the certificate authority processes your request you can disable the old website or run it on different ports.  When they do return your SSL be careful that installing it does not stop the live site.  That is, don't run the inactive site on port 443 lest you stop the live site.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 6, there is no way to put the old certificate back on without deleting the pending request which will make the certificate that the CA issues useless. But you can create a new pending request at that point and have your CA reissue the certificate to get a new certificate that will work (any good CA will reissue your certificate for free).

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with the same problem, and found [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/53dfdb5e-6106-4d99-85bb-da199bc27c7e.mspx?mfr=true) on TechNet.
Just in case the URL changes (as they so often do on Microsoft's sites) the article is entitled "Install certificate after deleting the pending certificate request (IIS 6.0)".

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising.